# Should ledger BIP-44 paths have four elements or five?

Tags: ledger, hsm

What is the correct BIP-44 path structure for the Tezos ledger apps? Should it have five path components (as Galleon uses) or four (as tezos-client and Tezbox use)?

The [BIP-44 spec](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0044.mediawiki) defines 5 levels of path and uses all 5 in all of its examples. It's not apparent that the final "index" component is optional.

Tezbox and tezos-client appear to default to the `m/44'/1729'/0'/0'` path, whereas Galleon defaults to `m/44'/1729'/0'/0'/0'`.

Comment: Do you have a link for the Galleon example by any chance?  A quick Google search turned up nothing.

Comment: When I start up the Galleon app on MacOS and connect to ledger, the app itself reports that path. There is also some mention at https://aloha.pheme.app/@umurb/e25d7fbc-b40f-48d2-bdff-c4c2f0353818

Comment: Ultimately it's a bit arbitrary, but I think it makes sense to try and follow bip 44 as much as possible and use 5.

Answer (score 12):

The Ledger app itself supports any length from 2 components up to 10, as long as the derivation path starts with 44'/1729'. This allows the Ledger to support either convention, and this support will continue into the indefinite future. As for which convention is better, that is a controversy quite outside of my scope as a Ledger developer :-) but there is no strong need to change conventions and any good tool should allow you to enter a custom path. Personally, I go with the tezos-client convention because I prefer the command line.

Comment: The command line default is not an immutable choice, maybe it might be worth confirming it to bip44