# Would it be possible to find a Derivation path for a public TZ1 address

Tags: ledger, wallets, tezbox

I can not find my original Ledger Derivation Path that i used. I have tried all combinations that are known to be the default values of Tezbox:
 44'/1729'/0'/0'
 44'/1729'
 44'/1729'/0'/1'
etc. 
None display my current public address.

Comment: We have noticed an edit which adds extra info into the post and it is large (from user @tndnz who is not you). The edit has been rejected. If you own the account that suggested that edit, then please don't do this again. Instead, edit your posts with your actual account, so that you can avoid confusions. 

Dark Peta: Are you user tndnz ?

Answer (score 5):

Assuming your PKH is a tz1* address, we would know 2/3 parts of how this address was derived, the only part missing would be your derivation path.

1 - seed phrase of the ledger device (assumed known via Ledger device ownership)

2 - tz1* = ed25519 signing curve

3 - Derivation Path

As noted on [this question](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/8/should-ledger-bip-44-paths-have-four-elements-or-five?rq=1) and yours, TezBox defaults to `44'/1729'/0'/0'`. Since you've mentioned that derivation path and the next increment of `/0'/1'` do not generate your PKH, the next steps I would take are:

1 - **Confirm that you are absolutely sure you have the device and signing curve correct**

2a - Run `tezos-client list connected ledgers` when Tezos Wallet is open on the device, then run the first `import` command it provides - `tezos-client import secret key ledger_yourstruly "ledger://adjective-animal-adjective-animal/ed25519/0'/0'"`, and then increment the derivation path and keep trying a reasonable number of combinations.

2b - You should also check the root path - `tezos-client import secret key ledger_yourstruly "ledger://adjective-animal-adjective-animal/ed25519/"`

Best of luck!